# How to use multiple wireless device and i have voucher for 1 device

Tags: mac-address, captive-portal

My internet provider is giving me an internet voucher for 1 device, so when I login with voucher in the Captive portal.

So is there any way or device which registers to this network with one MAC address and then gives internet to multiple devices?

Comment: Attach a router, use the Router MAC address and see if your ISP allows that within the plan you pay for.

Comment: use wifi sharing on the first device to the second